# How to take make and HTTP GET in android from ajax using new URLConnection

Tags: java, javascript, android, ajax, http-post

I've noticed that HtppClient has been deprecated and I want to update an old project and I am starting another new project, so I would like to not use deprecated code. Could someone show me the new way to do this in Android using URLConnection? I am at a little bit of a loss.  Any improvements on my methods that I currently use in java are welcome. Thanks in advance.

I mostly have ajax commands in javascript that work and want to create these in android java. (API 22+).

Ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'http://myurl/app_login.php',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     data: {email:myEmail, password:myPassword}, 
     success: function(data)    {
         callback(data);
     },
     error: function(data)  {
         callback(data);
     }    
 })
```

What I Used To Do:

```
final boolean myfunction(String user){
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.authorization_url));
    String body;
    body = "email=" + user;

    post.setHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try {
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(body,"UTF-8"));
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String json = reader.readLine();
            try {
                JSONObject finalResult = new JSONObject(json);

                //do stuff with final result

                return finalResult.getBoolean("success");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Relevant Imports for Code Above:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Bonus Question seeking answer:
I would greatly appreciate it if someone should show me the preferred way to do something like I do below since I upload a file. Sadly a lot of these methods/functions are now deprecated. This is similiar to the above question, but I do a file upload and wait for the `finally()` part of the `try{}`:

File Upload Code:

```
public String sendUploadFilePOST(FileData fileData, String acc, long parity){

        //setup variables
        String rqid = "FAILED";
        String boundary = "----------------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        File thisFile;
        //setup http post
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.uploadHandler_url));
        HttpResponse response;
        post.addHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        post.addHeader("Accept","*/*");
        post.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        post.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        try {

            File tempOutputDir = this.getCacheDir();
            thisFile = new File(tempOutputDir, fileData.fileName);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(thisFile);
            IOUtils.copy(getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileData.androidUri), outputStream);
            outputStream.close();

            fileData.sizeInBytes = thisFile.length();

            //create multipartentity
            MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            entityBuilder.setBoundary(boundary);
            //add file
            entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("doc", thisFile);
            //add content values
            entityBuilder.addTextBody("acc", acc);
            entityBuilder.addTextBody("parity", 500000 + "");

            //setup entity
            HttpEntity myMultiEntity = entityBuilder.build();
            post.setEntity(myMultiEntity);

            //execute post
            response = client.execute(post);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return rqid;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return rqid;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return rqid;
        } finally {
            //client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            String doNothing = "";
        }


        try {
            //process the response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            rqid = reader.readLine();

            //--to-do-- think of something if the file wasn't able to be deleted
            boolean fileDeleted = thisFile.delete();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //return rqid value if it is FAILED then the try did not complete fully
        return rqid;
    }
```

Relevant Imports:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

Thanks in advance. Sorry for the overload of code, but just replicate the ajax if you can. I am just showing what I used to do and want to change.

Comment: [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) is a nice library which makes things like this easy, and is similar to HttpClient.